# Retrofit returns valid list but items members are null

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I have a problem pretty much the same as this: [retrofit returning valid json but pojo is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918648/retrofit-returning-valid-json-but-pojo-is-empty)

But my variables are not declared as static. The are all declared like:

```
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
```

I have tried removing the annotations, but that doesn't work.

what could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

Interface:

```
@GET("/MyController/MyAction/{name}")
    void getSomeData(@Path("name") String name, Callback<List<DataItem>> cb);
```

Comment: How does the interface look like?

Comment: Forgive me, forgot to add. See edit to my question. Pretty much the same as the other question I linked to.

Comment: How do you map `DataItem`? Is this key returned in the json response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show me the actual received data(JSON or XML)? It seems that your callback structure is not matching with your data. For example, it would be possible that your data may have array that have a name, and you ignored it.

In my case, I declared like this,

```
void getList(@Path("data") String data,//
            Callback<OrderList> callback);
```

OrderList is:

```
public class OrderList {
    List<Order> order_list;
}
```

And my data is:

```
{
    "order_list": 
        [
            { "id": "1001", "data": "a" },
            { "id": "1002", "data": "b" }
        ]
}
```

I mean, it seems that your data may have nested structure and your class may not matching with that.

Comment: my json is just an array of items, like your json, but without the 'order_list' node: [{"id": "1001", "data": "a"},{"id": "1001", "data": "a"},{etc}]

retrofit does add items to my list in the code but it would seem that the 'mappings' are not done correctly. Sorry, on a different PC at the moment so cannot get any of my code to post, but all my stuff looks exactly like the question I linked to (apart from the static modifier)